# giving input to highchart using JSON

Tags: highcharts, json

i'm new to highchart

using a default JSON value given by highchart team wrks fine here is the link

[default high chart values](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?)

but however when i try to give input as JSON as a local variable shows nothing in the graph, here is the code

```
var myval = new Array();
myval [0] = "1146096000000,69.36";
myval [1] = "1146182400000,70.39";
myval [2] = "1146441600000,69.60";

/******* OR ******/
```

`//var myval =  [ [1146096000000,69.36], [1146182400000,70.39], [1146441600000,69.60]];`

```
/***** DOESN'T WORk *****/



 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( myval );

        $.getJSON(obj, function(data) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 2
            },

            title : {
                text : 'value graph'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'val 1',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define myVal as:

```
var myVal = [ [1146096000000,69.36], [1146182400000,70.39], [1146441600000,69.60]];
```

then it is already json, and doesn't need to be parsed using parseJSON. You can simply set

```
data = myVal;
```

If myVal is defined as

```
var myval = new Array();
myval [0] = "1146096000000,69.36";
myval [1] = "1146182400000,70.39";
myval [2] = "1146441600000,69.60";
```

Then myval is a json object containing strings. You can either parse out each elemnt of the array (e.g. using split) or define it like this:

```
var myval = new Array();
myval [0] = [1146096000000,69.36];
myval [1] = [1146182400000,70.39];
myval [2] = [1146441600000,69.60];
```

in which case, it is also already a json object and won't need to be parsed.

The only time you need to parse JSON is if the original data is a string representation of a json object, e.g. when getting the data from an ajax call.

Comment: thanks it really helped a lot, need to learn basics of JSON :(